# Which layout manager is best suited for rows and columns representation

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager

I have 2 rows that has to be displayed each will be having 11 columns.  Like to know which is the best layout manager is best suitable for this. Components should be arranged from left to right

[image]

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: @AndrewThompson this image is only representation, i will have to put them with combo-box, spinner, textBox etc

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a case for [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

[image: JTable with components]

> .. will have to put them with combo-box, spinner, ..

See [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more details on customizing the component the user sees and controls. Note the table above uses a checkbox to indicate vegetarians.

---

OTOH if a `JTable` is the wrong fit for this use-case, the best (Java SE) layout manager for achieving it might be [`GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html).  Other Java SE layouts that might achieve it are `GridBagLayout` or nested `BoxLayout`/`GridLayout` as mentioned by Ray.

Going 3rd party the field is wide open.  (JGoodies) `FormLayout`, `MigLayout`.. I think there is even a `TableLayout` to be had some place.

Answer (score 4):

If you really know you need a *layout manager* as opposed to a component like a JTable, you should consider [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) or [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). GridLayout is specifically designed for rows and columns like you describe; while GridBagLayout gives you finer control and lets you diverge from a standard grid (for example, to do what you might do with rowspan or colspan in HTML).

[`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) is useful for a single row or single column.